# How can I see how many times a person came per month (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, datediff

For my stystem I want to know how many times a visitor came to my shop. I got wifi sensors and they get alot of addresses and I want to know how many times the visitors came in a month

[This is the database I use (time is in unix time and get fixed with FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time)](https://gyazo.com/7439993a2e50d2cc7cfc54dc73de6538)

So what I want to get is a the address with the number of visits last month.(per day not per address so if he came 5times a day count it as 1)

Comment: Post the table as plain text. Show the SQL you have tried and explain why it doesn't work for you. Define what is "last month" for you. The last 30 days? The last 31 days? March?

Comment: I didnt try anything because I dont know where to start and by month I mean something like March, April

Comment: It's hard to guess where you are stuck. You only want data of one month. So what should you do? Use a `WHERE` clause of course. You want one record per person. So what should you do? `GROUP BY` person naturally. You want to count distinct days, so use `COUNT(DISTINCT )` on the day. Try to write that query and come back if you have issues with it you cannot solve.

Comment: And again: **post the table as text**, if you want help. It also helps to show the desired output for the shown sample table data. But as mentioned, for now you should try to solve this by yourself. It is not that difficult. Come back if necessary.

Comment: I know it is not that hard but in my I know what to do but to typ it is a second thing. And everytime if I see how its done I learn from it and know it for the next time! btw next time ill post a table as text! :)

Comment: i thought something like this :       
select bezoeker, 
  datum, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT sensordata1.address) "Bezoekers"

from
(
  select 
    address as bezoeker,
    from_unixtime((sensordata1.time), '%m') as datum
  from sensordata1 
Where (FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%m') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#)
) t
group by bezoeker,datum

Comment: You want to count distinct days, but '%m' gets you the month number. And what you actually count in your query is addresses, when you want to count days. So do that step by step: Use '%Y-%m' and compare with '2017-03'. Use '%Y-%m-%d' to get the day. Then count days per visitor.

Comment: I am strugling so hard atm and I need to get it done soon ... But I will keep trying it with your tips I gues ...

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried allot yesterday but didnt get it this is what I got now: select address,
       from_unixtime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') as datum,
       count(distinct floor(address) / (24*60*60)) as Aantalkeer
from sensordata1
Where (FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#)
group by datum,address;

Comment: You are grouping by day. How could you possibly get a count *per month* when you are grouping *per day*? Well, just wait, I'll post an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to see March 2017. So restrict your results to March 2017 in the `WHERE` clause. You want one result row per visitor (address). So `GROUP BY` address. You want to count each day just once. So `COUNT DISTINCT` days.

```
select 
  address,
  count(distinct from_unixtime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%m-%d'))
from sensordata1 
where from_unixtime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%m') = '2017-03'
group by address;
```

If you want this more flexible, i.e. always the last month when executing the query instead of 2017-03 fixed, then find today, subtract a month, and take the month got thus.

Comment: Sorry for the other post didnt see your answer! But thx for this answer the only thing is that I want this te be from the month we are in now not from a set month

Comment: So what keeps you from doing this? This is not a code writing service. You have all the information you need. Simnply replace `'2017-03'` with code to get year and month from the current date. Start doing something on your own instead of having us write the exact query you need.

Comment: the problem is I tried using: MONTH(getdate()) but the program I use as dashboard doesnt allow me to use this so I cant get how to set the current month now.

Comment: You want `'%Y-%m'`. To get this from a date (e.g. `CURDATE()`) you'd use `DATE_FORMAT`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html. `GETDATE` is SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Okay! thx for that tip! select 
  address,
  count(distinct from_unixtime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS frequentie
from sensordata1 
where from_unixtime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#
group by address; this is what I got now and I want to group from highest number to lowest number how do I do that?

Comment: You want to sort your results. Use an `ORDER BY` clause to do this.